# Sphinx PHP library returns different results from the Sphinx MySQL interfance

Tags: php, sql, sphinx, sphinxql

If i run the 2 peices of code to get Sphinx results:

One in PHP:

```
$host = \Config::get('sphinxsearch::host');
$port = \Config::get('sphinxsearch::port');
$s = new \Sphinx\SphinxClient();
$s->setServer($host, $port);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM essays,posts LIMIT  1, 15;";
var_dump($s->query( $sql, "essays,posts" ));
```

Returns : 5 rows with a total count of 5 rows (which is wrong)

And then in SSH:

```
mysql -h0 -P9306
SELECT * FROM essays,posts LIMIT  1, 15
```

Returns : 15 rows with a total count of 3514 rows (which is correct)

The MySQL window does the "essays,posts" correctly. But using `SphinxClient::query` does not. If i do just `FROM essays` in `SphinxClient::query` its fine.

I've looked around and can find very little on this.

Im using Sphinx 2.1.7

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umm, SphinxClient class is for **SphinxAPI** . You pass the query() function a full text search directly. NOT a SQL statement.

When you run

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM essays,posts LIMIT  1, 15;";
 var_dump($s->query( $sql, "essays,posts" ));
```

You are looking for documents that contain the words 'select', 'from', 'essays', 'posts', 'limit', '1' and '15'. Only documents containing ALL those words will be returned - you must have 5 documents with all those words.

To get all documents, sort of your example $sql, you would use

```
$s->setLimits(1,15);
var_dump($s->query( "", "essays,posts" ));
```

---

If you want to query sphinx via SphinxQL syntax, which sort of mimics mysql, then you need to use a **MySQL client** in your code - NOT Sphinx

Client. ie use mysqli, pdo etc, to run queries.

Comment: Thank you. My pride is slightly damaged thought.